# AngularJS Simple ng-switch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

No error is visible. Is something wrong with this ng-switch directive or do i've an issue somewhere else ?

Controller

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.model.error = 1;
}]);
```

View

```
<div ng-switch="model.error">
    <label ng-switch-when="1">Error: Username do not exists.</label>
    <label ng-switch-when="2">Error: Password is incorrect.</label>
    <label ng-switch-when="3">Error: Username is already taken.</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use http://plnkr.co/ to demonstrate your code. 

There could be a lot of reason for that. E.g: app was not bootstrapped correctly, not controller set for that element scope... etc

Comment: Just want to know if there is something missing there. The project is very complex. Just looking for a typo etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with ngSwitch. Problem was that you were not initializing your variable **$scope.model** hence you must be getting error in your browser console.

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'error' of undefined
```

Use

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.model = {}; //Added the line to initializing variable.
   $scope.model.error = 1;
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/16fXBYEMWaa6N6QAixSi?p=preview)

Comment: Not getting this kind of error for some reason. Thanks.